# C++ Non Template Method in Template Class

Tags: c++, templates, struct

Is it posible to write implementation of non template method in template class(struct) at .cpp file? I have read that template method should be written on .h, but my method is not template method although it belongs to template class. Here is the code in my .h:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef KEY_VALUE_H
#define KEY_VALUE_H

using namespace std;

namespace types
{
    template <class T, class U>
    struct key_value
    {
        T key;
        U value;

        static key_value<T, U> make(T key, U value)
        {
            key_value<T, U> kv;

            kv.key = key;
            kv.value = value;

            return kv;
        };

        string serialize()
        {
            // Code to serialize here I want to write in .cpp but fails.
        }
    };
}


#endif /* KEY_VALUE_H */
```

I tried to write the implementation of method `serialize()` in .cpp file like this:

```
#include "key_value.h"

using namespace types;

template <class T, class U>
string key_value<T, U>::serialize()
{
    // Code here returning string
}
```

Ended up with error: `Redefinition of 'serialize'`

How is the proper way to doing this?

Comment: 1. Don't put `using namespace std;` in header files.  2. Define the method in your header.

Comment: Won't serialise use the templated member data types? So it's dependent on the type of the template and will be different for each instantion type.

Comment: If you instantiate the template for every possible combination of template types, you can put the definition in a cpp file.

Comment: If the serialize member function is *truly* independent of the template arguments, which I doubt in this case, you could move it to a non-template base class of your template class and implement it in a .cpp file.

Comment: I've asked something similar a long time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213959/linking-template-class-functions

Comment: You can -and usually should- refactor non-template methods from template classes that *don't depend on the template parameters* into members functions of a non-template helper class, and those helpers you *can* put into .cpp files. This way, you curb *template bloat* by not letting the compiler duplicate those functions for different template instantiations.

Comment: PeterWood, I thought I can use string stream so it will not depend on data type. dhavenith & rhalbersma, thank you guys, that is exactly I will do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible<sup>*</sup>. Think about why templates need to be in header files in the first place: so that every .cpp file which uses code instantiated from a template can access it (templates are instantiated on demand only).

So in a way, you can think of a class template as a template for data layout (data members) plus a set of templates, one for each member function. Therefore, all members of a template class are treated as templates. You can even explicitly specialise a member function of a class template.

<sup>*</sup> As always, if explicit instantiation is an option, you can define the member function in a .cpp file and provide all required expicit instantiations in that .cpp file.

Comment: Oh, so it is not possible. OK then, I guess I should put the implementation in other utility class like people said in above comment. Thank you for your input Sir! :)